# FtpResponse21: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. Chilkat FTP and FileZilla Server

Tags: c#, ftp, chilkat

I am using Chilkat FTP component to download some files from an FTP Server running FileZilla Server. Following is the error message when I try to do so.

```
ChilkatLog:
  GetFile:
    DllDate: Sep 10 2010
    UnlockPrefix: MYFTP
    Username: Admin
    Component: .NET 2.0
    localFilename: C:\Site\Code\Project\Station\project_station_r3.zip
    ModeZ: 0
    BinaryMode: 1
    Passive transfer mode
    hostAddr: 172.21.14.64
    DataConnect:
      hostname: 172.21.14.64
      port: 2487
      ConnectTimeoutMs: 60000
      myIP: 172.21.14.64
      myPort: 2488
      connect successful.
    PassiveDataConnectionSetupTimeMs: Elapsed time: 0 millisec
    RetrFilename: [/Site/Code/Project/Station/project_station_r3.zip]
    RETR failed
    Filename: /Site/Code/Project/Station/project_station_r3.zip
    FtpResponse21: 550 /Site/Code/Project/Station/project_station_r3.zip: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
    TotalTimeMs: Elapsed time: 15 millisec
    Failed.
```

The file is there, and I can download it manually using FileZilla FTP client. Can anybody tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh... is this FTP server on your local host? It sure looks it - `myIP` and `hostname` are the same. In that case, you're trying to write the same file over itself, roundabout through the loopback interface. The error you're getting is reasonably descriptive - FileZilla Server has the file open for reading, and you're trying to write to it.

Try storing to a different filename.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `myIP` and `hostname` are the same.

Comment: Not very helpful when you cant see where the file is open to even close it

Answer (score 1):

in plesk
disable or shutdown iis pool

then upload your file